# How would I move this floating div?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm making a simple WordPress theme and I wanted to include a jQuery Sidr into and I got that done properly, however the menu icon that pulls the slide-in sidebar disappears behind the sidebar leaving the user with no way to collapse the sidebar again.

The theme is far from complete (and I was working on it using an offline WP setup) but I put it up here temporarily for the sake of this question: http://sweven.vhbelvadi.com

The menu icon in question is on the top-right. I have given it top and right properties, floated it right, as well as given it a fixed position to make it stay there.

As I said, the design is far from complete, so take no notice of it, but once you click on the icon to slide out the sidebar area, the menu icon disappears.

I have tried giving it a z-index which works, putting the menu button on top and makes it accessible, but you cannot see it on the link above because I removed it; didn't like the look of it.

Basically, I'd like to know if there's any way of changing the attribute (focus, active don't seem to work) or do anything else so once the sidebar opens the menu icon slides out alongside it.

What is my solution?

Thanks.

**Update:**

Right now I'm using the following code at the link above:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$('span.genericon').on('click', function(){
     $('#simple-menu').sidr({side: "right"});   
    $('span.genericon').css({
        right: "6.5em"
    }, 500);
});
 });
```

It works, but how would I return the menu icon to its original place?

Answer (score 0):

The collapse button is there but when the sidebar opens, the button goes behind it, so you need to change the CSS based on whether sidebar is visible or hidden, so use a kind of toggle like below.

```
$('button').toggle(
function() {
    $('#B').css('left', '0')
}, function() {
    $('#B').css('left', '200px')
})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hThGb/1/)

[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/patrickhaede/n9MLk/) (by [Patrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3126997/patrick))

Answer (score 0):

When you trigger the jQuery to move the menu to make it slide out, use the jquery animate command to change the "right" property of this menu icon (.genericon.genericon-menu) to 270px.

So, something along the lines of this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.genericon.genericon-menu').on('click', function(){
    $('#idofmenu').//code to move the menu out;

    $('this').animate({
        right: "270px"
    }, 500);
});
});
```

And then vice versa for when the menu collapses.

Comment: I tried this:

$(document).ready(function(){
$('span.genericon').on('click', function(){
    $('#simple-menu').sidr({side: "right"});
    $('this').animate({
        right: "6em"
    }, 500);
});
});

but it doesn't seem to work. I've also now restored the z-index so I can see the menu-icon.

Comment: OK, instead of animate, this seems to work: .css({ right: "6em" }, 500); But how would I close it? Confessedly, I am no whiz at jQuery!

Comment: To close it just add the opposite code in the function that closes the menu.  So you'd have right: 0 in that code.